# How to limit zoom in QtCharts?

Tags: c++, qt, plot

I have implemented the zoom example from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-zoomlinechart-example.html

Now I need to limit the zoom. I have two Y axis with values -100 to +100 (or even bigger), the other y2 axis is fixed at -pi..pi (no values outside of that range)

The zoom shall not be greater than the boundaries of the data ranges, or at least the limits shall be setable.

So how can I implement this? I found no further examples for QtCharts so far.

Also I would like to reset the zoom to original, let say with Backspace. How would I reset the zoom ?

Comment: total guess, but maybe: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html#setRange

Comment: Ok, but how can I check the range? How can I access the axis if I only have the chart as an object? How do I catch that a zoom happens?

Comment: There is a `rangeChanged(qreal min, qreal max)` signal I could catch, but where can I connect it ?

Comment: unfortunately, I have very little knowledge of QT.   Those links were just waht I found in 30s on google.

Comment: After you call void QChart::zoomIn, couldn't you just check the axis and adjust them as needed?  Or don't even use zoomIn, just adjust the range by hand.

Comment: I rather want to catch something like `OnZoom` in case somewhere outside of my code a zoom can be triggered. Also I do not want to zoom (maybe even plot) and then zoom back. That does not look nice.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that the graph will zoom between two consecutive statements in your code.   Just try it and see how it works.

Comment: Ok, but how do I access the axes? There is an axisX (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#axisX) and axisY, but how do I access the second Y axis?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#axes ?

Comment: That gives me a list of all axes. How do I know which one is attached to which side ? It could be obvious if there was only a little code example...

Comment: no clue.   liek I said, this is just off looking at the docs.   never used it

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but as there as are no others..

In `MyChartView : public QtCharts::QChartView` class I override `mouseReleaseEvent` with this method. When right clicking axis will be immediately 'zoomed out' to default (which is what I want).

In case zoom out should be supported in steps, I suppose connecting to QValueAxis::maxChanged/QValueAxis::minChanged and check range there could be done.

```
void MyChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
   if (event->button() == Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton) {
       // continue with zoom in
        QtCharts::QChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
   }
   else if (event->button() == Qt::MouseButton::RightButton) {
      // reset axis to default
      axisY_->setMin(0);
      axisY_->setMax(10);
      axisX_->setMin(0);
      axisX_->setMax(10);
   }
}
```